# Time Difference in Redshift

Tags: sql, amazon-redshift, date-arithmetic

how to get exact time Difference between two column

eg:

```
   col1 date is 2014-09-21 02:00:00
   col2 date is 2014-09-22 01:00:00
```

output like

```
result: 23:00:00
```

I am getting result like

```
 Hours Minutes Seconds
 --------------------
  3    3       20
  1    2       30
```

using the following query

```
SELECT start_time,
       end_time,
       DATE_PART(H,end_time) - DATE_PART(H,start_time) AS Hours,
       DATE_PART(M,end_time) - DATE_PART(M,start_time) AS Minutes,
       DATE_PART(S,end_time) - DATE_PART(S,start_time) AS Seconds
FROM user_session
```

but i need like

```
 Difference 
 -----------
  03:03:20
  01:02:30
```

Comment: Maybe you can do some manual operations using `DATEDIFF` (E.g.: `DATEDIFF(hours, date1, date2)` ) ...

Comment: its will retrieve only the hours but i need HH:MI:SS

Comment: It was only an example for hours. I suggest you to use similar functions for other date parts and do some operations with them.

Comment: i tried some function but none is working. post me if you know anything

Comment: anyone, reply to this question?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Use DATEDIFF to get the seconds between the two datetimes:

```
DATEDIFF(second,'2014-09-23 00:00:00.000','2014-09-23 01:23:45.000')
```

Then use DATEADD to add the seconds to '1900-01-01 00:00:00':

```
DATEADD(seconds,5025,'1900-01-01 00:00:00')
```

<strike>Then CAST the result to a TIME data type (note that this limits you to 24 hours **max**):</strike>

```
CAST('1900-01-01 01:23:45' as TIME)
```

Then LTRIM the date part of the value off the TIME data (as discovered by Benny). Redshift does not allow use of TIME on *actual* stored data:

```
LTRIM('1900-01-01 01:23:45','1900-01-01')
```

Now, do it in a single step:

```
SELECT LTRIM(DATEADD(seconds,DATEDIFF(second,'2014-09-23 00:00:00','2014-09-23 01:23:45.000'),'1900-01-01 00:00:00'),'1900-01-01');
```

:)

Comment: i use ltrim() instead of cast().

Comment: This is fantastic.

Comment: this seems neat, i did find that is was less performant than our needs required.  we were trying to find the min max and avg of the ltrim-dateadd-datediff and it was too expensive on 300 million rows to be useful even as a one-off solution.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT LTRIM(DATEADD(seconds,DATEDIFF(second,'2014-09-23 00:00:00','2014-09-23 01:23:45.000'),'1900-01-01 00:00:00'),'1900-01-01');
```